# Rotating, moving and scaling an object based on direction and the camera position, in Three.js

Tags: javascript, math, matrix, three.js, rotation

I'm working on a basic editor for Three.js. I want to be able to rotate, move and scale objects.

Using the basic function works but fine but is a bit confusing sometimes.

```
cube.rotation.z = Math.PI * val;
cube.rotation.x = Math.PI * val;
cube.position.z = val * -1;
cube.scale.y = val;
```

What I want to do is rotate the object in a direction instead of an axis and from the angle of the camera.

Here's a codepen illustrating this.
https://codepen.io/arpo/pen/LxyoRJ

It works fine as long as the other inputs is untouched. 
If you drag the range "Rotate Left Right" it rotates the cube on the z axis. But if you drag the range "Rotate Back Front" all the way to the right and then drag the "Rotate Left Right" again the rotation looks like it's on the Y  axis. The same goes for the other inputs.

I understand why this happen but I don't know how to get the desired effect. I also would like this to work from the cameras perspective. So that if you move the camera to the left and the drag the range "Move Back Forward" the cube should move away or get closer.

So what I want is that when you rotate the cube using the rotate left/right range I want it to swing left or right from the users perspective. If you use the move away range I want the cube to be pushed away from the user.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question requires at least basic understanding of how coordinate systems in 3D work. There are three coordinate system you need to know about:

1. **Local**: Each object in the scene has its own coordinate system. A set of 3 invisible axes which are centered in the object and always point to the same parts of the object no matter what transformation you apply.
2. **Global**: Also known as world coordinates, the scene has a global coordinate system which is used to describe position of the objects within the scene. The two red lines in your demo are the X and Z global coordinate axes.
3. **Camera**: The camera has its own coordinate system. Again, these are 3 invisible axes, one pointing leftwards, one upwards and one pointing towards the scene.

These 3 coordinate systems are not aligned. Well, they are aligned by default but not after you rotate the object or the camera.

When you rotate an object by its `rotation` property, you're rotating it around its local axes. Your cube starts with its Z axis identical to the world Z axis. Picture this as a line protruding from its front face aligned with the global red line. Then you rotate the cube 90 degrees 'back to front' and its Z axis now faces down.

Naturally, your 'left to right' rotation -- which is in fact Z axis rotation -- now rotates the cube around this down-facing Z axis.

In order to rotate the cube around an axis which is aligned with the camera coordinate system, you would have to perform several rotation and translation transformations.

I recommend learning a bit about the coordinate systems, model transformation, view transformation and related fundamentals of 3D. Otherwise it will all be very confusing.

Comment: Yes I know about this, hence "I understand why this happen but I don't know how to get the desired effect."

Comment: Could you please specify what exactly the desired effect is? Rotation about world axes or camera axes? And what should be the rotation center -- object center or world center? Those are 4 options in total and each one works differently.

Comment: I know this is hard to explain. What I want is that when you rotate the cube using the rotate left/right range I want it to swing left or right from the users perspective. If you use the move away range I want the cube to be pushed away from the user. I think this has to do with matrix manipulations but my knowledge is not there yet. I guess asking questions here is a part of learning about it.